# Embedding vlc player in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

How to integrate vlc player in vb.net? Can anybody help me ? I am using visual studio 2008.
In my project i was using Windows media player before,but because of some problems occured in project.I wanted to switc my video player to vlc player..

My pc configuration:-
1)64 bit 
2)Windows 8 pro 9200

Hoping that someone will  help me.

My email Id - mayurpatil0123@gmail.com

AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.currentPosition=reader.getString(5)
AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play()

Above code i have used for windows media player, I am searching for foe alternative for same code wic relates to vlc player.

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest version of VLC, i'm sure it will work anyway, but just to have the same setup as me.

Add the `VLC ActiveX` as a component to the VB5 /6 project, it will put 2 traffic cones into the toolbox, called `VLCPLugin` and `VLCPlugin2`.

Place a new VLCPlugin control on your form and size it suitably, and add the following code to a button or the form load:

```
VLCPlugin1.addTarget "c:\winvideo\sample.avi", Null, VLCPlayListInsert, -666
VLCPlugin1.play
```

If you turn on autoplay, or use a vlc play list option with the word "go" in it, it will play the clip automatically.

You can use the fullscreen option to put it into fullscreen mode.

[SOURCE](http://www.a1vbcode.com/vbforums/Topic25428-3-1.aspx)